# using JS object as Cache for APIs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
   const [cache,setCache] = useState({});
   const data = [{url:"http://.."} , {url:"http://.."} , {url:"http://.."}];
   return (
     data.map( item,ind  => (<ChildComponent item={item} setCache={setCache} cache={cache} /> ) )
          )
}

const ChildComponent = ({item,setCache,cache}) => {

const [img,setImg] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    const setVal = async () => {
      const val = await getProfilePic(item.url); //api
      setCache({...cache ,[item.url]:val})
      setImg(val);
    };
    if(cache[item.url]) 
    { return setImg(cache[item.url]) }
    else { setVal(); }

} ,[])

  return (
    <div> <img src={img} /> </div>
   )
}
```

here the url in the array variable *data* can be the same. In that case, it should not call the API again but should take from the variable cache. 
The problem in the above case is when the second item in the array is used for rendering child component, it's not getting the value which we set using the in the first render(using the first item in the array). How can I achieve this ?

Comment: You can't modify the `props` as they are expected to be immutable. You could use the parent state to achieve a cache, passing a setter to children, but in your case, the solution is simply to fetch in the parent and let the parent manage all the calls, the cache, etc. and adjust the rendering in the loading state or wait before rendering.

Comment: I think that is good idea. how can we do this,  *adjust the rendering in the loading state or wait before rendering*

Comment: and can you add it as an answer ?

Comment: Reading your code again and I'm thinking, are these just images that you want to display with `<img src={item.url} />` at some point?

Comment: yes, mistakenly wrote it inside div. I will edit question

Comment: Then don't waste your time with caching and fetching, let the browser do that job and just put `<img src={item.url} />` directly in the child components.

Comment: sorry I will get one blob file from that url , that I need to fetch from the api, that blob file I will use as the source

Comment: `const getProfilePic = (function() { const cache = {}; return function(url) { if (cache[url] === undefined) { cache[url] = fetch(url).then(res => res.blob()); } return cache[url]; }; }());`

Comment: the thing I want to know is how to acheive this,"adjust the rendering in the loading state or wait before" as @EmileBergeron suggested

Comment: @abidh just use conditional rendering: e.g. `{this.state.cache[item.url] && <ChildComponent {...childProps} />}`